# Mutate column name containing #

Tags: r, tidyverse, readxl

I have what I think is a simple problem. I imported a series of datasets with common columns, and one of the columns has a "#" at the beginning. It also is a mixed numeric/character variable across datasets, so I am trying to convert it to a character variable so I can drop the problematic values and reconvert to numeric. Is there a way to do this using tidyverse?

```
path="insertpathhere"
data_files <- list.files("insertpathhere", pattern=".xlsx$")

single_data_frame = map_df(data_files, .id='file_ID', function(file) {
  readxl::read_excel(paste0(insertpathhere,
                            file), col_names = TRUE, skip = 4)%>%
  mutate(healthprofessionalcount=as.character(c("# OF PHYSICIANS")))%>%
  select(!c('# OF PHYSICIANS'))
})
```

Comment: Use backquotes instead of quotes and drop the `c()` i.e. `# OF PHYSICIANS` (wrapped in backquotes)

Comment: I would have imagined that `read_excel` would have sanitized the column names. (But I was wrong.) Need to use this info. -> Per docs: `The value .name_repair = "universal" goes further and makes column names syntactic, i.e. makes sure they don’t contain any forbidden characters or reserved words. This makes life easier if you use packages like ggplot2 and dplyr downstream, because the column names will “just work” everywhere and won’t require protection via backtick quotes.`